# Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'ArrayList<Object>' in PostMapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, binding, type-conversion

I am looking for a working use case for the following :

```
@PostMapping("/add-gateway")
public String addGateway(ModelMap model, @Valid Gateway gateway, BindingResult result) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println("GatewayController has thrown error!");
        return "gateway";
    }

    service.addGateway(gateway.getId(), gateway.getGatewayName(), gateway.getIpAddress(), gateway.getDevices());
    return "redirect:/list-gateways";
}
```

Here is my Gateway class:

```
public class Gateway {

    private String id;
    private String gatewayName;
    private String ipAddress;
    private List<Device> devices;

    @NotNull(message = "Empty gateway name not allowed!")
    @Size(min = 5, message = "Enter at least 5 characters!")

    public Gateway() {
        super();
    }

    public Gateway(String id, String gatewayName, String ipAddress, List<Device> exampleDevices) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.gatewayName = gatewayName;
        this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
        this.devices = exampleDevices;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getGatewayName() {
        return gatewayName;
    }

    public void setGatewayName(String gwName) {
        this.gatewayName = gwName;
    }

    public String getIpAddress() {
        return ipAddress;
    }

    public void setIpAddress(String ipAddress) {
        this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
    }

    public List<Device> getDevices() {
        return devices;
    }

    public void setDevices(ArrayList<Device> devices) {
        this.devices = devices;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + Integer.parseInt(id);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Gateway other = (Gateway) obj;
        if (id != other.id) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public Map<String, List<Device>> getGatewayAndDevices(Gateway gateway) {
        return (Map<String, List<Device>>) new HashMap().put(gateway.getGatewayName(), gateway.getDevices());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Gateway [id=%s, gatewayName=%s, ipAddress=%s, devices=%s]", id, gatewayName, ipAddress,
                devices);
    }
}
```

The program fails on the returned "gateway" String, because one of the parameters of the Gateway constructor is an ArrayList of Objects, so that I never add a new Gateway to the list of Gateways and never return "redirect:/list-gateways"... I tried lots of workarounds for parsing the ArrayList to String, or using a Converter class, or playing with the initBinder method, however none of them seems to work here...I will greatly appreciate your help, because I need a working solution until the end of tomorrow! Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can your share gateway class? and is it your class, I mean can you change it? and what's the input of the api?

Comment: Hi, I added my Gateway class down below

Comment: Hey, I have added your code in your question, can you delete your code from the answer.